# Making my Rails asset pipeline HTTPS friendly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, https, asset-pipeline

My Rails website uses SSL and I had issues with Internet Explorer displaying this error message
[image]

I noticed that my CSS files are probably the culprit. My CSS files are in the asset pipeline (/app/assets/stylesheets). I only use HTTPS on my website so I want to make them HTTPS friendly. I included this line into `config/asset.rb` as well as into `config/environment/production.rb` for good measure

```
config.asset_path = "https://www.myapp.com/assets/"
```

Is there anything else that need to be to make the asset pipeline HTTPS friendly?

Comment: does it work like this?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting the same as before. Any ideas if using a CDN asset host like amazon S3 or cloudfront could solve this problem?

Comment: not a dupe, this is a clarified version honing on the specific issue

Answer (score 0):

If you use relative paths, you shouldn't have to worry about this..

Are you using helpers to load your assets?

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
```

generates:

```
<link href="/application.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

which shouldn't give you any problems with HTTPS... no other configuration required, off the top of my head.

Comment: I think the bootstrap gem (`https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass`)is causing this security warning issue. Locally, all of the stylesheets from this gem are located in `C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\bootstrap-sass-2.1.0.0\vendor\assets\stylesheets`. And I'm importing this into my custom.css.scss stylesheet inside the myapp folder (app\assets\stylesheets). Do you know how I can fix this for production?